# Error while passing file path arguments to cmd script that has a tr -d unix command

Tags: windows, bash, command-line, sed

In a windows environment, I'm trying to pass input and output file paths to a cmd script that is as follows:

```
rem trim CTRL-Z char
tr -d '\032' < %1 > %2
```

The function of the script is trimming a char from test1.txt and putting the contents in test2.txt

this is how I'm trying to do that:

```
C:\Users\a\Desktop>script.cmd test1.txt test2.txt
```

and this is the output I'm getting:

```
rem trim CTRL-Z char

tr -d '\032'  0<test1.txt 1>test2.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The script basically should run the command

```
tr -d '\032' < test1.txt > test2.txt
```

Would you please point out what I am doing wrong here? Where do those 0 and 1 come from in the output before the greater and less than signs?

Thanks in advance!

Bonus question: I'd rather do this trimming in the same file but as far as know you can't do in-place processing with "tr" command and "sed -i" chokes on the CTRL-Z char, so it's unusable. Any known workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command worked fine for me on Windows. Try running the following sequence on the command to see where the issue is.

```
tr --help
tr -d '\032' test1.txt
```

The 0 and 1 simply indicate the stdin and stdout